# Load old cart order in commerce

Tags: views, commerce

As I understand it commerce gets the users highest numbered order that is not yet completed (on the customers end) and uses that when a user adds an item to their cart or views their cart however I created a module that will allow a single user to create many carts (lets call these quotes) for their customers and i need a way for them to be able to go back and edit a previous quote or complete checkout on a previous quote right now i have a list of quotes in a view (any order that has not passed the checkout review page) and I want to add a column containing a link or button that will allow them to load that order number as the current cart I tried using a custom module function with a call to

```
commerce_cart_order_load(1);
```

(from a menu link) which is a previous order on my account however that appears to do nothing

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong/ what I need to do to make this work?

I would be perfectly happy doing this with views php if there is a function to set the users cart order that I'm missing, or by storing an OrderID hidden on the users profile

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much playing and breaking I wrote some code in a custom module to save the current order to load to the users profile in a un-editable field

```
    function create_new_quote_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['create_new_quote'] = array(
    'title' => 'Start New Quote',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'page callback' => 'custom_callback',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  $items['quotes/%/Load'] = array(   // assuming you want to make this dynamic
    'title' => 'Quotes',
    'page callback' => 'create_new_quote_LoadQuote',
    'page arguments' => array(1),   // references %, i'm assuming this is all dynamic
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),  // don't do this, whatever permission you want goes here
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  return $items;
}

function custom_callback () {
  global $user;
  $currentOID;
  $user_full = user_load($user->uid);
  $currentOID = commerce_cart_order_new($user->uid);

  $updateUserParams = (array) $user_full;
    $updateUserParams['field_currentcartorder'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = intval($currentOID->order_id);

    unset($fullUser->pass);
    unset($updateUserParams['pass']);

    user_save($user_full, $updateUserParams);
drupal_set_message(t('You have Created a New Quote #'). $currentOID->order_id,'status');
drupal_goto('moulding');
}

function create_new_quote_LoadQuote($quote_to_load) {
  global $user;
  $user_full = user_load($user->uid);

  $updateUserParams = (array) $user_full;
    $updateUserParams['field_currentcartorder'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = intval($quote_to_load);

    unset($fullUser->pass);
    unset($updateUserParams['pass']);

user_save($user_full, $updateUserParams);
drupal_set_message(t('You Loaded Quote #'). $quote_to_load,'status');
drupal_goto('quotes');
}


function create_new_quote_commerce_cart_order_id($uid) {
  global $user;
  $user_full = user_load($user->uid);
  $orderidentifier = $user_full->field_currentcartorder['und'][0]['value'];
  $orderidentifier = intval($orderidentifier);
  return $orderidentifier;
}
```

excuse my uncommented code and poor module name but I got it working this this code set so I can now create and change orders from my view by pasing Quotes/[orderid]/Load via a link